# PHP missing - SSL cert - Subdreamer

Tags: php, xml, ssl

Okay. Please be patient as I am handed this situation and PHP/coding aren't my strong points/day-to-day job.

website: thetuitionsolution .com / client_login

Our client asked for an SSL certificate for their website. We provided so by using the web hosting site and it worked.

Now the PHP login page won't allow clients to log in. I tried using Chrome Dev Tools and it gave me this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https :// www.thetuitionsolution.com/Client_Login' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http :// thetuitionsolution.com/Client_Login'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

Which is great. I have a solution. I just can't find the PHP (or XML?) file to edit the content.

[Pastebin of the page that needs edited](http://pastebin.com/6Ugt85qE)

The website is hosted through PowWeb and the file isn't anywhere in their file manager. It appears whoever made this website used Subdreamer.com and I checked the admin panel there and no luck either.

Many thanks. Please let me know if I am not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
<form action="http://thetuitionsolution.com/Client_Login" method="post">
```

You are using HTTP protocol on a HTTPS page, and the browser thinks, that it's insecure.

You need to change the action attribute:

```
<form action="/Client_Login" method="post">
```

Use a relative link, and this code will work for both protocols and for any domain, if you would like to transfer your site.

Comment: My problem is that the file isn't anywhere on the hosting site. I'm looking for an XML right? Whoever coded this didn't document and used some goofy template thing.

Comment: @iammartyr This is not a file. It's a SEF URL, pointing to a script, that will process login. Did you try my code?

Comment: No. I didn't because I can't find the SEF URL to edit the contents of the code. That is where I am stuck. I do not know what I am looking for.

Comment: @iammartyr Open your XML file, find the code `<form action="http://thetuitionsolution.com/Client_Login" method="post">` and change it to the code I gave.

Comment: You must think I'm nuts or stupid, or both. There is no XML files hosted on the web server. I have no idea what file the script is referencing when it is ran. I searched for " *.xml " and nothing comes up. It's using some weird template from Subdreamer.com

Comment: @iammartyr "There is no XML files hosted on the web server" - but what file did you put into pastebin?

Comment: @iammartyr "I have no idea what file the script is referencing when it is ran" - you need to find this file. We won't be able to help you in this task.